# Unable to install logstash plugin

Tags: logstash

Logstash 5.1.1 on Windows 7 32bit, trying without success to install logstash-filter-elapsed. Below the method I tried.

Before running plugin installer, I run:

```
set DEBUG=1
```

to show debug output.

Then I run:

```
logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-elapsed
```

This fails both when I'm in my corporate network (with proxy) and when using a network without proxy, with the following error:

```
Looking if package named: logstash-filter-elapsed exists at https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elapsed/logstash-filter-elapsed-5.1.1.zip
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused
          initialize at org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:126
                open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1197
             connect at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:763
             timeout at org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:98
             connect at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:763
            do_start at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:756
               start at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:745
               start at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:557
               start at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/utils/http_client.rb:13
  remote_file_exist? at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/utils/http_client.rb:23
   get_installer_for at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/pack_fetch_strategy/repository.rb:27
              create at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/install_strategy_factory.rb:15
                each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
              create at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/install_strategy_factory.rb:14
             execute at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/lib/pluginmanager/install.rb:27
                 run at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67
             execute at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:11
                 run at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67
                 run at C:/tools/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132
              (root) at C:\tools\logstash-5.1.1\lib\pluginmanager\main.rb:46
```

It seems that there's a timeout in contacting the url "https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elapsed/logstash-filter-elapsed-5.1.1.zip".

Opening this url in a browser returns an xml with an error message (seems like the xml you when trying to access a not existing object from a AWS S3 bucket).

Adding the `--no-verify` flag yelds the same result.

**EDIT**

I tried to bypass this problematic "Looking if package named:..." step: I edited `logstash-5.1.1\lib\pluginmanager\pack_fetch_strategy\repository.rb`, adding a `return nil` at the beginning of the `def get_installer_for(plugin_name)`.

Running the installation, I get another error:

```
Installing logstash-filter-elapsed
Error Bundler::HTTPError, retrying 1/10
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Error Bundler::HTTPError, retrying 2/10
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
...
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but since logstash sucks so big time on windows I gave up. I would suggest to open a elastic bug report and be done with it.

Comment: @eckes done: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6529 . Let's see what feedback I get.